# Grouping values from one column that fall between other column values plus conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to merge two data frames that look as below:

```html
unit      start    stop
A      0.0    8.15
B      9.18   11.98
A     13.07   13.80
B     13.82   15.00
A     16.46   17.58
```

---

```
df_2
time    other_data
1            5
2            5
3            6
4            10
5            5
6            2
7            1
8            5
9            5
10           7
11           5
12           5
13           5
14           10
15           5
16           4
17           4
18           4
```

I want to merge df_2.other_data onto df_1. However, I want to group df_2.other_data where df_2.time is between df_1.start_time and df_2.stop_time.

From each group I want to extract the following number based on the pseudo-code below:

```
for other_data between start_time and stop_time:
   if 1 or 2 in other_data:
       value = other_data.min()
   elif 10 in other_data and 1 or 2 not in other_data:
        value = other_data.max()
   elif other_data.mode() > 1:
        value = other_data.min()
   else:
        value = other_data.mode()
```

For the first example group [5, 5, 6], the value would be 5, the mode. For the second example group [6, 10, 5, 2], the value would be 2.

This should result in a df that looks like this:

```
unit      start    stop  other_data
A      0.0    8.15         1   
B      9.18   11.98        5
A     13.07   13.80        5
B     13.82   15.00        10
A     16.46   17.58        4
```

However, with the code below I get this result:

```html
m = np.greater_equal.outer(df_2.time.values, df_1.start.values) & \
    np.less_equal.outer(df_2.time.values, df_1.stop.values)

def logic(s):
    if s.isin([1,2]).any(): return s.min()
    if s.isin([10]).any(): return s.max()
    return s.mode()[0]

df_1['other_data'] = df_2.other_data.groupby(m.cumsum(1).argmax(1)).agg(logic)


      start    stop other_data
0      7.53    8.15          1
1      9.18   11.98          5
2     13.07   13.80        NaN
3     13.82   15.00         10
4     16.46   17.58        NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely avoid the loops and go with a vectorized solution.

```
m = np.greater_equal.outer(df2.time.values, df.start_time.values) & \
    np.less_equal.outer(df2.time.values, df.stop_time.values)
```

```
def logic(s):
    if s.isin([1,2]).any(): return s.min()
    if s.isin([10]).any(): return s.max()
    return s.mode()
```

```
df['other_data'] = df2.other_data.groupby(m.cumsum(1).argmax(1)).agg(logic)
```

---

```
  unit  start_time  stop_time  other_data
0    A         0.0        3.2           5
1    B         3.3        6.1           2
2    A         6.2       10.5           1
3    B        10.6       13.2           5
4    A        13.3       16.0          10
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited the original question with new data, the function that I'm using that you supplied, and the result I get. I'll be curious if it works for you. I added an additional statement in the pseudo code to take the smaller value if there are two modes, which you'll see shows up in the example. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Disregard changes to pseudocode, fixed the multiple mode issue with 'return s.mode()[0]

Comment: @connor449 the code works fine with `s.mode()[0]` ! There is one `NaN` but that's because there are no `time` between 13.07 and 13.80 in the second `df` ;)

Comment: Gotcha, that makes perfect sense. I remedied the issue for now by rounding the start and stop time columns. Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a while loop that adds values into each row until df_2.time is out of range.

first you create a list:

`other_data = []`

then you do something like this:

```py
i = 0
j = 0
while i < len(df_1["unit"]) and j < len(df_2["time"]):
    current_row = []
    while df_2["time"][j] > df_1["start_time"][i] and df_2["time"][j] < df_1["stop_time"][i]:
        current_row.append(df_2["other_data"][j])
        j += 1
    i += 1
    other_data.append(current_row)
```

You can then easily turn `other_data` to a numpy array and append it to your dataframe.
You may want to change the conditions of the range as you prefer.